# How to set max char length in a line when printing reciept vertically using JPOS

Tags: java, printers

The requirement is to print the receipt vertically and there should be minimum 80 chars in a line.
To print the reciept vertically I have added following lines:

```
posPrinter.rotatePrint(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, POSPrinterConst.PTR_RP_RIGHT90);
```

this code is able to print the receipt vertically, but the problem is that it is printing only 69 characters in a line, and my requirement is to print 80 characters in a line.

Please help me How can I resolve this.

Thanks in advance.